# Type inference in the source of OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml, unification

I would like to take a close look at the implementation of type inference in OCaml, my OCaml seems be installed in `/usr/local/lib/ocaml`, but no `.ml` inside seems include the piece of code for type inference...

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a binary release of OCaml. You need the sources. You can get the sources from this page: [OCaml 4.00.1 Release](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/release.en.html#id239715)

Comment: Then the inference part is in `otherlibs/labltk/browser/typecheck.ml`? It does not look like...

Comment: No, that's just a piece of the ocamlbrowser, I belive. The type checking appears to be in the directory named `typing`. The file `typing/typecore.ml` says that it does type checking for the core language. That might be a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from looking at the source code, you might find [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/refinements/papers/PottierRemy04/hmx.pdf) useful.